# Does it make sense building a Knowledge Base using headless CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, aem, headless-cms

Situation:

- I work for a multinational/global organization in the HR dept as Engineering Manager.
- HR needs a lot of content related to Immigration, Benefits, Leaves, Disability, Transfers, New Hire Onboarding, Covid Policies, Expense Policies.
- These are rendered thru documents/Knowledge bases. As you can imagine for a global corporation that is present in multiple countries this problem can get very complex soon.
- Almost all of the content is in terms of text/documents that are not really structured.
- Today we are using AEM as the Content Management Platform. AEM was being used in a headful manner but AEM imposed a lot of restrictions when we had to develop Applications on top of AEM
- So we are going to use AEM in a headless manner and bring in all the content in content fragments so that those content fragments can be rendered on different portals (some use cases need more than 15 portals)

Questions:

1. Does it make sense imposing structure on these documents?
2. Does continuing to use AEM make sense here?
3. We want to enable reuse of pages : One page is rendered on multiple platforms.
4. We want to enable reuse of text blocks: One block of text could be used on multiple platforms.
5. How do we derive information such as breadcrumbs?
6. How do we build an information tree: e.g. article A , B , C should be shown under US-> Leaves-> Maternal leaves while D,E,F should show under Global -> Leaves -> Bearevent Leaves. That information is not going to be present in content fragments.
7. How do we build a site map?
8. How do authors discover information? If I write a content fragment - how do I manage its taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case - AEM also delivers *any* content as json or xml. Or, if your sling models are set up for model.json, you even get a json representation with all the context you need.

So I am not really convinced that this statement is true:

> AEM imposed a lot of restrictions when we had to develop Applications
> on top of AEM

I have seen projects using experience fragments combined with content fragments in "real" AEM pages. That way you can reuse and combine content parts on several levels and even make use of the multi site manager feature.

Using tags or custom metadata fields (based on a central taxonomy) will help you add information you might need to display content parts without enclosing elements. All you need is a servlet that returns all the content or experience fragments with the right tags attached.
It's hard to tell you more here without doing the complete rwquirements engineering ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in AEM,

3. do via writing different scripts that use different selectors
4. do via using reference components
5. perhaps render breadcrumbs using page path
6. use a tree structure of tags and tag the items accordingly
7. you may want to create a custom left side authoring pane picker

The other things are more complex (site maps!) but all can be done with AEM.
You can also use AEM to do some of those things and do other ones outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to answer it :

1. Does it make sense imposing structure on these documents?

- Structuring document will give you more control over content, even better to strategies it. It will help in several things such as planning, searching, filtering.

2. Does continuing to use AEM make sense here?

- I don’t know your exact business entirely however if content have more static content unlike real time websites live update in data then it will help surly.
  in addition, CMS market AEM mold good in compare with other CMS such as Sitecore. others CMS using databases whereas AEM content repository. it is debatable which is good

3. We want to enable reuse of pages : One page is rendered on multiple platforms.

- if you are saying pages means it an HTML experience division of page. AEM has good feature of experience Fragment. Yes, there is challenges but still this will fit efficiently

4. We want to enable reuse of text blocks: One block of text could be used on multiple platforms.

- Here also experience fragment can be a good fit, make as many variants as possible you want and reuse it

5. How do we derive information such as breadcrumbs?

- I do not know exact wanting here but I would say implement multiple breadcrumbs for small segments or can implement custom breadcrumbs to target content small segments accordingly. Here if you content is well designed then breadcrumbs will not be real challenge

6. How do we build an information tree: e.g. article A , B , C should be shown under US-> Leaves-> Maternal leaves while D,E,F should show under Global -> Leaves -> Bearevent Leaves. That information is not going to be present in content fragments.

- You can also manage it through Template and restrict the template in a way that page will be created under certain tree. In other way, make taxonomy in such a way it creates structure you have given for example parent page (HR work, Engineering) for each and every business unit its ok to have redundant content, use MSM feature also tag them meaningful way.

7. How do we build a site map?

- As in breadcrumbs, you can also build sitemaps for small segments such as one for HR/US and Engineering/US render them individual or together it does not matter. It will be still well design sitemap

8. How do authors discover information? If I write a content fragment - how do I manage its taxonomy?

- Either to make folder structure in certain way or make variants and use tagging framework

To conclude - No product will be 100% fit for any requirement, it’s just you have to use the product in such a way it will be more and more suitable for your requirement.
Good luck!

Comment: Just a side node: AEM does support database as persitance layer for content. Most customers of AEM uses the content repository as default option.